# how to deploy to aws using ci/cd for zappa(python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm using zappa to deploy on aws. And I wanted to implement CI/CD on AWS.
So, I created a pipeline and successfully did Aws COMMIT and AWS BUILD.

I'm unable to deploy the same using AWS CODE DEPLOY.

The Buildspec.yaml looks like this:

```
version: 0.2


    phases:
      install:
        commands:
          - echo Setting up virtualenv
          - python -m venv venv
          - source venv/bin/activate
          - echo Installing requirements from file
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
      build:
        commands:
          - echo Build started on `date`
          - echo Building and running tests
          - python tests.py
          - flask db upgrade
      post_build:
        commands:
          - echo Build completed on `date`
          - echo Starting deployment
          - zappa update dev
          - echo Deployment completed
```

How should I execute zappa deploy  or zappa update  on AWS?

I'm not sure how to add create **appspec.yaml** file.

Please HELP! Stuck!!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. Do you intend to update and then deploy a new version of your application with zappa through codebuild right everytime you push changes to your repository ~ which I assume code is hosted in AWS CodeCommit?

Comment: @groobienewbie Yes Exactly. I want to update zappa everytime i push code to COdeCOmmit. But for some reason it is crashing on aws. How do I get the code deploy to work for zappa. I've update the spec file above. PLease take a look. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `buildspec.yml` file that I use. You could adjust this to suit your needs (for example, including the DB upgrade command).

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - mkdir /tmp/src/
      - mv $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/* /tmp/src/
      - cd /tmp/src/
      - python3 -m venv docker_env && source docker_env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3 && pip install -r requirements.txt && zappa update production && deactivate && rm -rf docker_env
  post_build:
    commands:
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - rm -rf /tmp/src/
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

Note that this is using the Docker image `danielwhatmuff/zappa:python3.6` in CodeBuild. I use this image as it's based on AWS Lambda and has been tuned for Zappa.

Comment: How do you execute the same in codeDEPLOY? I'm stuck here for sometime now and there no documentations online for the same.. It's a very simple requirement.

Comment: I get this error in codebuild: Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: python3 -m venv docker_env && source docker_env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3 && pip install -r requirements.txt && zappa update production && deactivate && rm -rf docker_env. Reason: exit status 127

Comment: Also, is this for **buildspec** or **appspec**??

Comment: Also, can i deploy this on lambda or on ec2? I want to deploy it using lambda itself. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar - did you end up using this method, (running it out of codebuild and declaring it in the buildspec.yml) ?

Answer (score -1):

Zappa update to Code Deploy:
Your Buildspec.yaml looks fair good but there is one important point to consider.

Postbuild will always run regardless of success/failure. Debug information can be pulled from a failed build.

Either check the reason for failure from build log, or modify your yml to look like below (caution: this is only draft change, test before using in systems):

```
version: 0.2
  phases:
    install:
      commands:
        - yum -y groupinstall development
        - yum -y install zlib-devel
        - yum -y install openssl-devel
        - wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
        - tar xJf Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
        - cd Python-3.6.0
        - ./configure
        - make
        - make install 
        - ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
        - curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
        - python3 get-pip.py
        - pip3 install virtualenv
        - virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv
        - source venv/bin/activate
        - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    build:
      commands:
        - echo Build started on `date`
        - echo Building and running tests
        - python3 tests.py
        - flask db upgrade
    post_build:
      commands:
        - if [ $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING = 1 ]; then echo Build completed on `date`; echo Starting deployment; zappa update dev; else echo Build failed ignoring deployment; fi
        - echo Deployment completed
```

Hope it answers.

Zappa update to AWS

Below are the steps to do Zappa update on AWS

1. Configure AWS with IAM user
2. Configure AWS cli in the local host using command
     a. pip install awscli
     b. aws configure
3. Call "Zappa init", it will generate zappa_settings.json based on details provided
4. Zappa deploy `<name provided for environment in step3>`

Now your application will be deployed to AWS. Whenever you need to update call

Zappa update `<name provided for environment in step3>`

Comment: Hi Ganesh, The app spec file was giving me an error which says invalid file and always failed the deploy part. Also, here whe can i specify python version for eg: **image:python3.6** . Like in gitlab or bitbucket. How can will code deploy know that it is python and a particular version!

Comment: Jason, OS image can be either linux/windows according aws specifications for code deploy. You are not installing python3.6 hence whatever system default python level is there, that will be used. By Default, python -> represents python 2.x version. If you want to install Python3.6,  just follow like below in install phase
yum install -y python3.6
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

then wherever you are calling python, replace it with python3.6.

Comment: Please can you help me create an Appspec file to run the same?? I'll be very grateful!

Comment: Updated draft file info the answer. Please double check to meet your standard before testing.

Comment: I keep getting this error! **The deployment failed because the AppSpec file that specifies the AWS Lambda deployment configuration is missing or has an invalid configuration. An unrecoginzed property was found in the AppSpec file. The template cannot be parsed.**

Comment: How can I fix it? Also, I am using **AWS LAMBDA** for deployment and not EC2 or EBS!